# Multiple images using css3 in opera 12

Tags: html, css

I am using a multiple image in my css, it looks OK in firefox and chrome latest version however the opera v12.0 it doesnt position my second picture well. It shows it to the middle of the page(even though opera 12 supports multiple image).

here is the css i am using:

```
body{
background:url(../images/bg.png) top repeat-x,url(../images/bg_footer.png) bottom repeat-x, #fff;
}
```

tried also this:(same result)

body{

```
background-image: url('../images/bg.png'), url('../images/bg_footer.png');
background-position: left top, left bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

}

any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url(../images/bg.png), url(../images/bg_footer.png);
background-position: left top, left bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Comment: Same result :S
btw: thnx for such a fast reply

Comment: Edited the answer to not use shorthand - try that.

Comment: @user1469025 No, sorry :( Sounds like a bug in Opera, as there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: fixed it...
problem was coming from another div...

btw: is there any way to hack IE to support multiple images???

Comment: @user1469025 The only ways I can think of would be to use background divs (set a negative z-index on them) which contain the images as single css backgrounds and use javascript to set the height and width to the dimensions of the images and/or percentage of the document height/width (depending on your requirements). Sounds more complex than it would be, but that's pretty much how it was done before css3. Alternatively, you could fake it in IE < 9 only: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><!--><html class="ltie9"><!--<![endif]-->` and give `html.ltie9 body { background: ... }` a special composite bg image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 display: inline-block;
background-image: url('../images/bg.png'), url('../images/bg_footer.png');
background-position: left top, left bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
```